# API REST format is correct?

Tags: api, rest

I have a question about format of API REST

I have different API :

```
GET /api/payment/providers
GET /api/payment/recipients
GET /api/payment/rules
DELETE /api/payment/rules/{uuid}
PUT /api/payment/rules/{uuid}
POST /api/payment/rules
```

Is this format correct?

Or should I have something like that :

```
GET /api/paymentProviders
GET /api/paymentRecipients
GET /api/paymentRules
DELETE /api/paymentRules/{uuid}
PUT /api/paymentRules/{uuid}
POST /api/paymentRules
```

I heard that REST must respect this format:

```
Resource list / specific resource / sub-resource list / specific sub-resource / etc...
```

But, my format is correct or no?

Thanks!

Comment: I would enjoy more the first one.

Comment: Yes, I prefer the first one, but some of my team members told me it's not a good REST format... Who is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: your resource identifiers are *fine* as is.

> I heard that REST must respect this format:

No.

You can use any spelling conventions you like for your resource identifiers.

[RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-A) defines the production rules for URI, and [HTTP Semantics](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-4.2) defines a more restricted set of rules to follow when using the http/https URI scheme.

But neither of these put any *semantic* restrictions on the use of path segments.

Resource identifiers are similar to variable names - the machines don't care what spellings you use, so you can choose any spelling you like.  The best spellings to use are those that are most convenient for the people you care most about.